# What's the meaning of Rssi in android WifiManager

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to get the signal strength of the current wifi connection using `getRssi()`

```
private void checkWifi(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        Log.i("WIFI CONNECTION", "No connection");
    } else {
        int netType = Info.getType();
        int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

        if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed();
            int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
            Log.i("WIFI CONNECTION", "Wifi connection speed: "+linkSpeed + " rssi: "+rssi);


        //Need to get wifi strength
        } 
    }
}
```

thing is i get numbers like -35 or -47 ect.. and i don't understand their values..  I have looked at the android documentation and all it states:

> public int getRssi ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns the received signal strength indicator of
>   the current 802.11 network.
>
> This is not normalized, but should be!
>
> Returns the RSSI, in the range ??? to ???

can someone explain how to 'normalize' or understand these results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**According to IEEE 802.11 documentation**: Lesser negative values denotes higher signal strength.

*The range is between -100 to 0 dBm, closer to 0 is higher strength and vice-versa.*

Comment: but whats the range?  anyone?>

Comment: wait..  -100 is stronger than 0 no?

Comment: Nope. -100 is weaker than 0 or say even -99.

Comment: Thats not what the documentation says.. everyone says the "lower" the number the stronger the strength..

Comment: correction the documentation just says what i wrote in my original post.. but this link shows how most say the opposite of what you are saying: http://www.droidrzr.com/index.php/topic/664-how-do-i-interpret-signal-level-readings/page__p__18478#entry18478

Comment: if you look at that forum they are fighting over it and what I have written is correct. Take it from someone who has implemented 802.11i used by most of the OEMs currently.

Comment: You are right.. i did some manual tests... and sir you win!  thanks for helping me sort through the bad info

Comment: @erik 'lower' means 'less than', and -100 < -99 < 0. It does not mean 'closer to zero'

Answer (score 13):

I found this in [WifiManager.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L478) :

```
/** Anything worse than or equal to this will show 0 bars. */
private static final int MIN_RSSI = -100;

/** Anything better than or equal to this will show the max bars. */
private static final int MAX_RSSI = -55;
```

**Relevant rssi range on android is betwwen -100 and -55**.

There is this static method [WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi,numLevel)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#calculateSignalLevel(int,%20int)) that will compute the signal level for you :

```
int wifiLevel = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi,5);
```

is returning a number between 0 and 4 (i.e. numLevel-1) : the number of bars you see in toolbar.

**EDIT API 30+**

The static method is now deprecated and you should use the [instance method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#calculateSignalLevel(int))

```
wifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi)
```

Major difference is that the number of levels is now given by [`wifiManager.getMaxSignalLevel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getMaxSignalLevel())

Comment: Deprecated. It replaced with  public int calculateSignalLevel (int rssi)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#calculateSignalLevel(int)

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

> Vendors provide their own accuracy, granularity, and range for the
>   actual power (measured as mW or dBm) and their range of RSSI values
>   (from 0 to RSSI_Max).
>
> As an example, Cisco Systems cards have a RSSI_Max value of 100 and
>   will report 101 different power levels, where the RSSI value is 0 to
>   100. Another popular Wi-Fi chipset is made by Atheros. An Atheros based card will return an RSSI value of 0 to 127 (0x7f) with 128
>   (0x80) indicating an invalid value.

So this is strongly depends of equipment.

Answer (score 0):

starting from ben75's answer, we can use this method to normalize rssi:

```
public static int normalizeRssi(int rssi){
  // Anything worse than or equal to this will show 0 bars
  final int MIN_RSSI = -100;
  // Anything better than or equal to this will show the max bars.
  final int MAX_RSSI = -55;

  int range = MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI;
  return 100 - ((MAX_RSSI - rssi) * 100 / range);
}
```