# Determining how small is the distance between 2 devices

Tags: android

I have been searching the SO and I couldn't find a really good answer for it. Assuming that 2 android devices are 20-30 meters away and are approaching, I would like to somehow determine how close the are getting to each other until they are within 2-3 meters (or less).

The only option so far I can see is to enable bluetooth on the devices( and make them discoverable). Then I would monitor the RSSI of the service discovery. The problem with that is that everytime I need to enable bluetooth/make it discoverable, a user as has to confirm making in it a unreasonable when the app is in the background or when this need to be done multiple times.

Are there any other options/solutions to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I guess another solution would be to establish a Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer  connection and get its RSSI...Can't think of others without usage of GPS or similiar...

Comment: Thank you. I did search for the Wifi peer to peer but it does not seem to have the capability of returning RSSI (unless you can point me somewhere). From my reading it seems the RSSI is hardcoded in the code of android sdk

Comment: Also RSSI can vary between devices and orientations. One possible solution for how 'other services' work this out is to use hardware where all of characteristic are qualified.

Comment: some code to get the RSSI of Wi-Fi can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275306/whats-the-meaning-of-rssi-in-android-wifimanager . I don't think you will be getting the granularity you are searching from Wi-Fi, but only actual testing on your intended hardware and in your specific environment will provide you with a reliable answer whether it's possible to use this technique for this purpose...

Comment: This signal strength is only applicable for the generic wifi (device to access point) and not the wifi peer to peer. I read somewhere that the value of RSSI is hardcoded actually